# Weird terminal prompt

Tags: terminal

In my terminal, the prompt looks like this

```
$(get_virtual_env)user:~$(parse_git_repo)$(__git_ps1)
```

Does it entail that I am in a virtual environment? I tried running deactivate, but I get command not found error.

Comment: Try the `exit` command.

Comment: This exits the terminal process. I opened it again, and I get the same prompt